# IP Address in HEX representation

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

I'm getting strange IP address while do ping command to localhost by name:

```
C:\Users\user>ping gold

Pinging GOLD [fe80::c5f8:b871:61d:8182%5] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::c5f8:b871:61d:8182%5: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::c5f8:b871:61d:8182%5: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::c5f8:b871:61d:8182%5: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::c5f8:b871:61d:8182%5: time<1ms
```

My PC has only wifi network adapter and it's IP according `settings->wifi` is simple :

```
SSID:   SS
Protocol:   802.11ac
Security type:  WPA2-Personal
Network band:   5 GHz
Network channel:    104
IPv4 address:   192.168.1.189
IPv4 DNS servers:   192.168.1.254
Manufacturer:   Qualcomm Atheros Communications Inc.
Description:    Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A Wireless Network Adapter
Driver version: 12.0.0.312
Physical address (MAC): 58-00-E3-42-1F-2A
```

UPD :

I have disabled IPV6:

[image]

Comment: [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address)

Comment: That is an IPv6 link-local address.

Comment: But I have disabled IPV6. More details in question body UPD

Comment: Just because you've disabled ipv6 on a specific adaptor does not mean it is completely disabled. Localhost is not the same as your network card.

Comment: It takes a lot more than that to disable IPv6 on Windows, and completely disabling it voids Microsoft support because Windows uses it internally. It is very nearly 2019, and you should be actively using IPv6, at least alongside IPv4.

Comment: The number after the percent sign indicates the interface used (no. 5). With `route print` you get a list of interfaces with numbers and names. If you don’t want IPv6, you need to disable it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is an IPv6 address, which you can force to IPv4 using the -4 flag

```
ping hostname -4
```

Comment: But I have disabled IPV6. More details in question body UPD